# Sub-multiplicative function in expectation or pointwise?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis, integration

Consider the function that satisfies 
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(X)f(Y)]\leq \mathbb{E}[f(XY)],$$
where $X\in\mathbb{R}$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}$ are Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and correlation $\rho\in(-1,1)$. Is there a family of functions satisfying this relationship? More strongly, is there a family of functions that satisfy

$$ f(x)f(y)\leq f(xy)$$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\frac 12$ satisfies the desired relationship.